# Ajax of jQuery in IE 6 stops the whole script

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm trying to use some jQuery code for Ajax which works well in Firefox or IE version 8+ but I need to work in IE 6 as well, I have this code for toggle and use Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#S1").click(function 
            () {

            $("#t1").toggle("fast");
            $("#P1").toggle("fast");
            $("#S1").css("background-color", "White");
            var ID = $("#HiddenField1").attr("Value");
            var params = new Object();
            params.Key = ID;
            var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(params);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "viewMessages.aspx/readen",
                data: myJSONText,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",

            });
        });
    });
```

when I try to run this one in IE6 it won't work and in debugger I get
Line 29:
Error : Expected Identifier, String or Number, 
(line 29 would be end of Ajax function in my code)

I removed some code to see where the problem is, so I chnaged to this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#S1").click(function 
            () {

            $("#t1").toggle("fast");
            $("#P1").toggle("fast");
            $("#S1").css("background-color", "White");
            var ID = $("#HiddenField1").attr("Value");
            var params = new Object();
            params.Key = ID;
            var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(params);

        });
    });
```

this one toggles now but I get the error
Line21.
Error: JSON is unidentified,

where do you think the problem is? how can I run some code like this in IE6?
I'm developing in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra comma after the data type.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "viewMessages.aspx/readen",
    data: myJSONText,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"//,

 });
```

Also you don't need to stringify the data component nor do you need to declare an new Object.
it can just be `data:{'KEY':ID},`
To get id just use:

```
$("#HiddenField1").val();
```

Comment: Oh and IE doesn't have JSON object it's only in modern browsers.

Comment: thanks man, it worked, could you look at this as well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894223/sending-param-to-the-ajax-of-jquery-not-effective