# Sending Param to the Ajax of jQuery not effective

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax of jQuery, I have this code below and although I get no error in firebug it's not working, It seems the function in code behind doesn't get any params.

```
(document).ready(function () {
        $("#S1").click(function 
            () {

            $("#t1").toggle("fast");
            $("#P1").toggle("fast");
            $("#S1").css("background-color", "White");
            var ID = $("#HiddenField1").attr("Value");
            var params = { 'Key': ID };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "viewMessages.aspx/readen",
                data: params,                    
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });
    });
```

and here is the code behind

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
public static void  readen(string Key)
{
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.ReadenMes(Convert.ToInt32(Key));                
}
```

the code below work but since I wanna use it in IE 6 I have to use the code above.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#S2").click(function 
     () {
     $("#t2").toggle("fast");
     $("#P2").toggle("fast");
     $("#S2").css("background-color","White");
     var ID = $("#HiddenField2").attr("Value");
     var params = new Object();
     params.Key = ID;
     var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(params);
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "viewMessages.aspx/readen",
         data: myJSONText,
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: "json"

     });
 });
```

});

where do you think i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue only is that IE6 has no JSON.stringify method, than you can use [json2.js from Douglas Crockford](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and then your second sample should work as expected in IE6 too.

```
$(function () {
  $("#S2").click(function 
     $("#t2").toggle("fast");
     $("#P2").toggle("fast");
     $("#S2").css("background-color","White");
     var ID = $("#HiddenField2").attr("Value");
     var myJSONText = JSON.stringify({ Key: ID });
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "viewMessages.aspx/readen",
         data: myJSONText,
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: "json"
     });
  });
});
```

Another approach is do not use 'json' datatype, and then params should be serialized as regular query string.

```
$(function () {
  $("#S2").click(function 
     $("#t2").toggle("fast");
     $("#P2").toggle("fast");
     $("#S2").css("background-color","White");
     var ID = $("#HiddenField2").attr("Value");
     var params = { Key: ID };
     $.post("viewMessages.aspx/readen", params);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

[3 mistakes to avoid when using jQuery with ASP.NET AJAX](http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#S1").click(function 
        () {

        $("#t1").toggle("fast");
        $("#P1").toggle("fast");
        $("#S1").css("background-color", "White");
        var ID = $("#HiddenField1").val();
        var params = "{ 'Key':'" + ID + "'}"; //changes here
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "viewMessages.aspx/readen",
            data: params,                    
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks .I got rid of .attr() and Used .val() and used your code but not working.

Comment: Should ID be escaped as a string when constructing `params`?

Comment: it seems there is nothing wrong in firebug, Key gets the right value and and there is no error

Comment: added contentType, not sure what your default setting is

Comment: Don't stringify the params or the server won't see it. Should be: var params = { 'Key': ID};

Comment: the content type is not good, since it doesn't exist in IE 6 and my goal is get it working there

Comment: content type is fine as just "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

```
var ID = $("#HiddenField2").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "viewMessages.aspx/readen",
    data: {"KEY":ID},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"

 });
```

Also you don't need to stringify the data component nor do you need to declare an new Object.